# Difference between root ('/') and "Computer"

Tags: finder, filesystem, folders

If I open the finder and navigate to `Go>Computer`, then I am presented with all the mounts, while navigating to the root `/` using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> seems to be a different directory. In particular it seems to be only the main drive. Activating `show path bar` in the "view" of the finder does not help. The question is: what is the path to the `Go>Computer` view (as this seems to be the only way to navigate to mounts). Or: where are mounts located on the Mac?

It should not be so frustrating to simply access a mounted volume from the finder. And how can I put the `Go>Computer` folder into my favourites?

update: Below is a picture of the "documents" mount created by [cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/). Which was not in the "Favourites" until I dragged it there from the "Computer" view. Also the path in the bar just says "documents"

[image]

update 2: the preferences should result in all mounts being displayed in locations but the "documents" volume is not.

[image]

update 3: as per request the output of `mount`. I think I have initially confused the location `/System/Volumes` with `/Volumes` as the first one was findable using Finder before unhiding `/Volumes`. The mount does in fact appear in `/Volumes` using Finder after unhiding.

```
felix@stochastik3 ~ % mount
/dev/disk1s5s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s6 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
//DRIVE@localhost:49166/Google%20Drive on /Volumes/GoogleDrive (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, nobrowse, mounted by felix)
pCloud.fs on /Users/felix/pCloud Drive (pcloudfs, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by felix)
Cryptomator@macfuse0 on /Volumes/documents (macfuse, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by felix)
Cryptomator@macfuse1 on /Volumes/documents (lGpYQhph5FCp) (macfuse, nodev, nosuid, synchronous, mounted by felix)
```

Comment: Given the nature of Cryptomator, it may be doing something non-standard.

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `mount` and add the output (as text)?

Comment: @nohillside what do you mean by run mount? I did not mount that volume manually

Comment: Just run the command, it will show where the different volumes are mounted (including Cryptomator).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Computer" is a virtual construction which shows you all the mounted volumes, local network connections, and other things. It's not a 'real' place on a disk.

`/` is the root level of your system disk, usually "Macintosh HD". Mounted volumes are mounted under `/Volumes`, which is normally a hidden directory. They are not mounted at root.

You can set Finder Preferences to show "Computer" (normally "Felix's iMac" or whatever), and mounted volumes in the Sidebar of Finder windows, under the "Locations" heading, which is a different category from Favorites. You can swap the order to make Locations higher/lower than Favorites.

[image]

There are also settings to show mounted volumes on the Desktop.

[image]

The Finder tab and window name should show the path `/Volumes/my disk`, as here:

[image]

If you want to unhide /Volumes, you can do that with this command:

```
sudo chflags nohidden /Volumes
```

It will then appear normally under `Macintosh HD` in the Finder.

You can always find the full pathname of an object in the Finder by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>. This will copy the pathname of the object, which you can then paste somewhere to read.